# Read parasolid text *.x_t file from Solidworks using its schema definition

Tags: c++, schema, solidworks

Im assigned with a work where i should read parasolid text *.x_t(version 20) file generated from solidworks using the schema in cpp. But the schema(version 20) of each entity consists of some extra fields.

The schema file has been read in cpp and its definition is loaded(including no_of_fields and others) in a struct. I need to use this no_of_fields in loops to read *.x_t file for each entity. However, the no_of_fields in Body entity(for instance) is 31 in schema definition and 27 in parasolid text file of same versions. So I'm confused of proceeding further. Do anybody have ideas about using schema definition to read parasolid files?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The .x_t file might have been generated using version 20 of Parasolid, but an old schema.  In the .x_t file, there should be a line in the header like:

```
SCH=SCH_2201272_20000
```

The numbers after the last underscore indicate the schema.  I know that the Body entity in schema 18007 has 27 fields, but in schema 20000 it has 31.